# FPGA Routing general criteria

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl, logic-gates, intel-fpga

I was implementing a simple circuit on an FPGA using Quartus (6 logical elements) and I noticed that the block containing the 6 cells is located near the perimeter.
Is this a general criterion? The placing on the border can help to minimize some delay? (i.e. is it "nearer" to the output pins and this is beneficial)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot that goes into it, but I think it's safe to say the fitter decided the best place to put that block of logic is because it was right next to the FPGA pin. If your project has low timing requirements, it probably could have put that block of logic in a different spot and still had it meet timing requirements.

So to answer your question, yes there is some optimization that put that block of logic next to the port, and yes in an FPGA distance can equate to delay, because the further it is away the more logic and busses the signal has to traverse.

Here is a diagram of how logic gets compiled, the fitting takes the sythesized HDL and then decides where to put it. If it meets timing constraints then it can be compiled into a file to program the device with.

[image]

Comment: ``... the *best* place ...`` sounds weird. It's rather that the fitter chose a location which does meet all known constraints. It is not necessarily the best choice, but it's a sufficient choice.

Answer (score 0):

If your design contains any I/O, then at least the I/O part of it *will* be on the perimeter, because that's where the I/O interface is. The interface needs to be dedicated to that function because the currents are much higher, often the voltage swings are too, and protection against the world and its ESD is (relatively) big and bulky.

FPGAs have several levels of routing resources. They have a few lines that span the chip, many lines that span part of the chip, and a wealth of lines that connect to the adjacent logic. The router tries to favour putting connected regions next to each other so it can use the abundant resource, and save the rare resource for when it's really needed. In a simple design, it could place the logic away from the pins, but it isn't programmed to do that.

Comment: Not all FPGAs have all of their IOBs on the edge. For large pin count devices with a BGA die, many of the IOBs will be scattered around the whole die.